# Mass export all images as individual JPEGs in InDesign, but not use image frame ratio

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, jpg, indesign-scripting, script

I would like to mass export all linked images in a Indesign document using this script, its from [this thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/86724/mass-export-all-images-as-individual-jpegs-in-indesign/104784?noredirect=1#comment154756_104784)

```
var myDoc = app.activeDocument,
apis = myDoc.allPageItems, pageItem, fileName;

while ( pageItem = apis.pop() ) {
  if ( !pageItem.graphics[0].isValid ){ continue;}

  fileName = File ( pageItem.graphics[0].itemLink.filePath ).name;
  fileName = fileName.replace( /\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i, '.jpg' );

  app.jpegExportPreferences.exportResolution = 2400;
  app.jpegExportPreferences.jpegQuality = JPEGOptionsQuality.MAXIMUM;

  //give it a unique name
  var myFile = new File ("C:/Users/RANFacistol-Mata/Desktop/Image Trial/"+ fileName);


  pageItem.exportFile(ExportFormat.JPG, myFile);
}
```

When i use this script, it export the linked images in the ratio how its placed in Indesign.

How its exported
[image]

How it looks in Indesign
[image]

Yet i want it to look like this, the original ratio of the image
[image]

Comment: What about packaging your document and get the Links folder?

Comment: Unless we're missing something in what you are asking, Vinny's idea of doing a simple package/collect for output would give you all your linked images. You could then use PS to automate the resizing.

Comment: Yes i know that option, but title says mass export as individual jpgs. So i would like to know other options as well. The script is almost there yet exports the wrong ratio.

Answer (score 3):

You need to export the graphic, not the object.
Add .graphics[0] before the exportFile function.

```
var myDoc = app.activeDocument,
    apis = myDoc.links.everyItem().getElements(),
    items, fileName;
var i = 0;
var MyPath = "C:/Users/xx/Desktop/test/"; // change your path here

alert("Script is running. Press OK and wait until done...");

while (items = apis.pop()) {
    items = items.parent.parent;
    if (!(items.hasOwnProperty("graphics"))) {
    continue;
    }
    i++;
    try {
        fileName = File(items.graphics[0].itemLink.filePath).name;
        fileName = i + "_" + fileName.replace(/\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i, '.jpg');
    } catch (e) {};

    app.jpegExportPreferences.exportResolution = 2400;
    app.jpegExportPreferences.jpegQuality = JPEGOptionsQuality.MAXIMUM;

    //give it a unique name
    var myFile = new File(MyPath + fileName);

    items.graphics[0].exportFile(ExportFormat.JPG, myFile);
}

alert("Done");
```

**Edit:** Or... package your links and use Photoshop batch function to save everything in JPG

Comment: Thanks @Vinny!!! you made my day, next time i should better check the settings. hahhaa you added 2400 at MAXIMUM took quite a while doing 123 images ;)

Comment: Well I just copied/pasted the script you were referring to. 2400 is a lot indeed, but you can easily change that in the script...

Comment: Yes i know, 300 and MAXIMUM is good enough for me. Thanks again for the awesome adjustment!

Comment: How could i adjust this script so it export the placed image according to the frame. I know Indesign has the function export Selection. I cant figure out how to target that code?